# Steam does not start after install in 13.10

Tags: steam

I have installed steam on my Laptop running 13.10, When I click on steam icon, it wont launch,So I have given "steam" command in terminal.Following is the output

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 13.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140402034337_1.dmp
/home/saikiran/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755:  6814 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/saikiran/.steam/registry.vdf’: No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/saikiran/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-1e1a9170-2ae6-46c1-bc74-3c0db2140401
Running Steam on ubuntu 13.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/saikiran/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140402034339_1.dmp
/home/saikiran/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755:  6943 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-06b25061-5bb4-42c2-b835-bc2e92140401
```

I have tried removing ~/.steam/steam/appcache as indicated in other threads

I have installed Steam on Xubuntu 14.04 beta, still same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised a steam support ticket for this. They have given this [solution](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3134-TIAL-4638). When you face this cannot start registry.vdf is missing problem, you need to reset steam and restart the system.